# Getting WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j in embedded Java.

I want to start an in process server admin instance through the application that I have. I am not able to compile the application in Eclipse since right off the bat it says

"WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper cannot be resolved to a type". It is not able to resolve the line below

private WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv;

I appreciate any help in this matter.

See the class below that I have

```
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.GraphAlgoFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.PathFinder;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicRelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Expander;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Path;
import org.neo4j.kernel.Traversal;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Description;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Parameter;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginTarget;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Source;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;      // interface
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;  // interface
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.server.*;

public class DBFacade {

    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType { KNOWS }

    private GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    private WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv; 

    public void WriteNode(java.lang.String message)
    {
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx(); 
        try
        {     
            // Updating operations go here     
            Node node = graphDb.createNode();
            node.setProperty( "message", message );
            tx.success();
        }
        finally
        {     
            tx.finish(); 
        }
    }

    public void WriteRelationship(Node firstNode, Node secondNode, RelTypes type)
    {
        Relationship relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS ); 
        relationship.setProperty( "message", "brave Neo4j " ); 
    }

    public void CreateDB(java.lang.String path)
    {
        //newEmbeddedDatabase is an implemetation of GraphDatabaseService
        this.graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( path ); 
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        graphDb.shutdown(); 
    }

    public void StartAdminInstance()
    {
        // start web admin in process
        srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper( this.graphDb ); 
        srv.start(); // The server is now running // 
        //until we stop it: 
        srv.stop(); 
    }

    public void StopAdminInstance()
    {
        srv.stop(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a dependency management framework like Maven? You have to include the `neo4j-server` jar, which includes that Class.

You'll also need to update the `StartAdminInstance` to have `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper((AbstractGraphDatabase) graphDb);`

Comment: No I am not using maven. That is under System/lib. I will include that. Is there any other dependency that I may have to include?

Comment: You should include the neo4j jar as well, but other then that I'm not sure, I usually have Maven handle it all for me. If you can, I would recommend using something that manages your dependencies such as Maven.

Comment: ok I included neo4j-server-1.8.2.jar file in the build path from system\lib but now getting a new error

Comment: ok I included neo4j-server-1.8.2.jar file in the build path from system\lib but now getting a new error

Comment: ok I included neo4j-server-1.8.2.jar file in the build path from system\lib but now getting a new error The constructor WrappingNeoServerBootstapper is undefined